# Translate name to SID - Administrators VS Account Operators

Tags: c#, winapi, active-directory, ldap, sid

I'm using the Win32 method called "LookupAccountName" in order to translate name to SID.

When I try to translate the name "Administrators" I get an SID but when I try to translate the name "Account Operators" I get the following error:

`ERR#1332 - No mapping between account names and security IDs was done`

Also when I used the following command from CMD:

> wmic group where (name='administrators' and domain='%userdomain%') get
>   name,sid

I got an SID.

but when I used the following command from CMD:

> wmic group where (name='Account Operators' and domain='%userdomain%')
>   get name,sid

I got the following message : **"No Instance(s) Available".**

Can anyone explain to me what is the different between the two ? How is it possible that the translation of the "Administrators" group into an SID success while the translation of the "Account Operators" doesn't.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[MS.Support]: Well-known security identifiers in Windows operating systems](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/243330/well-known-security-identifiers-in-windows-operating-systems) briefly explains the difference between the two (look for *SID*s: ***S-1-5-32-544*** and ***S-1-5-32-548***). Regarding *Account Operators*:

> Description: A built-in group that exists only on domain controllers.

The errors you get (either from *LookupAccountName* or *wmic*) mean that the *Account Operators* group is not found.

Comment: Thank you for taking care of that. Now, I couldn't edit the post myself because of the 6 chars minimum limit. Is there something that I'm missing or do I have to earn some additional privilege to do that myself (briefly looking at your edit I didn't see any other changes)?

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain the error but you can ignore it in this instance; Account Operators is a [Well-known SID](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/243330) : `S-1-5-32-548`.